# Limit concurrent HTTP calls via vue-resource

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-resource

We perform multiple `$http.get` calls via vue-resource concurrently in our application. Is there any way to set a limit so that vue-resource queues the requests and executes the calls based on this limit?

Comment: Are you talking about limiting the calls of `$http.get()` at the same time?

Comment: @kevguy even if I call `$http.get()` 100 times in a second, if I set 10 concurrent request limit, Vue should queue the requests and wait other requests to run the new requests so that there won't be 11 http calls running at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use Vue-resource.

I simply wrap the promise by another promise:

```
const callBackFunction = function (valueToReturn, promise) {
  pendingRequestsArr.pop();
  if (waitingRequestsArr.length > 0) {
    executeXHR(waitingRequestsArr.shift())
  }
  if (valueToReturn.body && !valueToReturn.body.hasOwnProperty('error')) {
    if (promise) promise(valueToReturn.body.content || valueToReturn.body);
    return valueToReturn.body.content || valueToReturn.body;
  }
  else
    return valueToReturn.error
};

function executeXHR(obj) {
    if (!AJAX_CONCURRENT || pendingRequestsArr.length < AJAX_CONCURRENT) {
      pendingRequestsArr.push(obj.resource(obj.data).then((response) => callBackFunction(response, obj.promise)))
    } else {
      waitingRequestsArr.push(obj);
    }
}
function wrapPromise(resource, data){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    executeXHR({"resource": resource, "data": data, "promise": resolve});
  })
}
getAllProjects() {
        return wrapPromise($projects.get);//$project.get == $http.get('/projects')
      },
```